# Java web start - Unable to load resource

Tags: java, java-web-start

I've got a jar that loads great with java web start when I browse through the IP address of the server.
Once I try the server **name** instead I get the following exception:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource:
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The wrapped exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor2.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
  ... 15 more
```

JNLP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp
    spec="1.0+"
    codebase="http://servername/Site/Views/.."
    href="">
    <information>
        <title>title</title>
        <vendor>vendor</vendor>
        <description>description</description>
        <description kind="short">short</description>
        <icon href="../../icon.gif" />
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>

        <j2se version="1.5+" java-vm-args="-Xmx1000M -Xms150M" initial-heap-size="150M" max-heap-size="1000M" />
        <j2se version="1.4.2+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" java-vm-args="-Xmx1000M -Xms150M" initial-heap-size="150M" max-heap-size="1000M" />

        <jar href="/file.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com....">
        <argument>CD6B172DEC34924D83EA64A61A6550BE1271325929392</argument>
        <argument>http://servername/file.asp</argument>
        <argument>/Site</argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Any idea what should I look for?

Comment: what does your jnlp/webstart config file look like?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've changed the java proxy settings to direct connection - and it works.

Comment: Proxy setting can be found in the "Java Control Panel" (javacpl or "Configure Java" under windows)

Comment: It did not help me even after changing settings to direct connection.

Answer (score 6):

Try using [Janela](http://pscode.org/janela/) or [github](https://github.com/AlBundy33/JaNeLa) to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Include your IP address in your host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host) for the respective server:

Sample Entry:

10.100.101.102  server1.us.vijay.com        Vijay's Server

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, but I have looked at one of my jnlp files and I have put in the full path to each of my jar files.  (I have a velocity template that generates the app.jnlp file which places it in all the correct places when my maven build runs)

One thing I have seen happen is that the jnlp file is re-downloaded by the by the webstart runtime, and it uses the href attribute (which is left blank in your jnlp file) to re-download the file.  I would start there, and try adding the full path into the jnlp files too...I've found webstart to be a fickle mistress!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else gets here because they're trying to set up a Jenkins slave, then you need to set the url of the host to the one it's actually using.

On the host, go to Manage Jenkins > Configure System and edit "Jenkins URL"

Comment: This help when we try to add slave to the Jenkins master. You need to change the Jenkins URL to the one where you host the jenkins master.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same issue, i updated the hosts file with the server address and it worked

Answer (score 0):

changing java proxy settings to direct connection did not fix my issue.

What worked for me:

1. Run "Configure Java" as administrator.
2. Go to Advanced
3. Scroll to bottom
4. Under: "Advanced Security Settings" uncheck "Use SSL 2.0 compatible ClientHello format"
5. Save

Comment: Didn't worked for me :(

Answer (score 0):

this also worked for me , thanks a lot

changing java proxy settings to direct connection did not fix my issue.

What worked for me:

```
Run "Configure Java" as administrator.
Go to Advanced
Scroll to bottom
Under: "Advanced Security Settings" uncheck "Use SSL 2.0 compatible ClientHello format"
Save
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, and it was already unchecked.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

In Advance Tab -> scroll down and un-checked all options in advance security setting and try by checking one-by-one and finally app start running with one option TLS 1.1

that was the solution I got it.

Answer (score -1):

1. Disable all "MD5" containing lines from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_361\lib\security\java.security file

2.Add IP url in the exception configure java>>security>>Edit Site list

url example:https://10.50.25.58

Comment: Please format your answer.