# Java Web Start with Signed

Tags: java, http, jnlp, java-web-start

All,

I am having some trouble running a java web start application that has been generated by Netbeans 7.

I have migrated my existing java 6.9.1 application to Netbeans 7 and attempted to make it a web start application.

To do this I have checked the Enable Web Start option from the project properties.

For the codebase option I have Web Application Deployment selected.
The Application descriptor is selected option which will point the JNLP application-desc element to my applications main class.

For signing, I have generated a key and pointed the Signing properties at this.  I have the Mixed Code set to Trusted Only as my application will only used signed JARs.

When I compile, all referenced JAR files and the application JAR file are signed which is output in the console (for each one) as:

```
Signing JAR: D:\MyCode\dist\lib\somejarfile.jar to D:\MyCode\dist\lib\somejarfile.jar as signFiles
Enter Passphrase for keystore: Enter key password for signFiles:
```

**NOTE:** signFiles is the alias I have used in the Signing properties in Netbeans.

The following files are created in my dist folder:

- lib
- jnlpcomponent1.jnlp
- launch.html
- launch.jnlp
- README.TXT
- My App.jar

I have copied these to my web folder that is hosted under tomcat which is C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\mywebapp.

I am running from the following URL in IE and Firefox:
http://mylaptop:8080/mywebapp/launch.html

The following exception is thrown when I click the button in launch.html to launch the JNLP file:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: file:/C:/Users/panderson/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/Content.IE5/B3UCQV8C/$$codebase/launch.jnlp
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My launch.jnlp file has the following:

```
<jnlp codebase="$$codebase" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
...
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="My App.jar" main="true"/>
...
```

I am not too sure why it is looking under the temp folders in internet explorer for it...

... But I have tried putting the full url in the jnlp href to the launch.JNLP file http://mylaptop:8080/mywebapp/launch.jnlp then it throws the following exception:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: file:/C:/Users/panderson/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/Content.IE5/DR2O6URQ/$$codebase/My App.jar
```

If I then change the jar href to http://mylaptop:8080/mywebapp/My App.jar, the following exception is thrown when I click the button in the launch.html to run the launch.JNLP file.

```
BadFieldException[ The field <jnlp>codebase has an invalid value: $$codebase,$$codebase]
```

Any help or thoughts?

Cheers,

Andez

Comment: @Andrew - Was hopefully going to be a JWS issue.  Just with netbeans - it sometimes hides the potential problems from you which hit you head on when you run things. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<jnlp codebase="$$codebase" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
```

These $$ place-holder values are usually translated to something sensible by a servlet or similar functionality.

Comment: Hey Andrew, you just beat me to this.  There are a couple of issues with it.  First thing as you mentioned was the codebase.  I have changed this to the URL e.g. http://mylaptop:8080/mewebapp.  Secondly there appears to be an issue with the name of my JAR file.  As it has a space in the filename, it came up with the unable to load resource file.

Comment: Spaces in HTML should generally be replaced by ..I think it is `%20`.  But then, I avoid using caps. or spaces in Jar names.  Instead of spaces, a `.` or `-` or `_` will generally suffice.

Answer (score 2):

This was suggested as a useful tool in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643893/java-web-start-unable-to-load-resource).

Try using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) and see if it finds any problems with your JNLP file.

Further double check and make sure the `codebase` url matches the url of your server/application.

Comment: +1 Bloody good point!  JaNeLA would have picked up all kinds of problems with that JNLP, starting with the codebase.

Comment: Thanks for the link with Janela.  Will come in handy.